# Different datetime formats pandas can auto detect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

```
In [29]: import pandas as pd
In [30]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["02-04-1995","02/04/1996", "12/31/1996"]))
Out[30]:
0   1995-02-04
1   1996-02-04
2   1996-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I have given 2 different datetime formats. Pandas can autodetect the format. In the value `12/31/1996` I have given in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. It can still detect the correct format without explicitly giving it.

So, Which all formats or values can pandas `to_datetime()` can auto-detect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start looking into `dateutil` module (for example [here](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/fc9b1625ebc729f01e449879b6b140abd12ae621/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L266)), how this module parses string for datetime:

```
JUMP = [" ", ".", ",", ";", "-", "/", "'",
        "at", "on", "and", "ad", "m", "t", "of",
        "st", "nd", "rd", "th"]
```

According to this, you can do:

```
print( pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["02and04and1995","02'04'1996", "12;31;1996"])) )
```

Prints:

```
0   1995-02-04
1   1996-02-04
2   1996-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```